# Testcase selection in CPPUnit

Tags: cppunit

Is it possible to select which test cases to run in CPPUnit like it is done in NUnit? May be using some config file?

Thanks, Rakesh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MFCTestRunner if you're looking for a GUI where you can click to select tests.

You'll have to edit your test main application if you want to select which test to run via config file.  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783690/how-to-run-subset-of-unit-tests-in-cppunit-by-selecting-them-at-run-time/2786251#2786251) that might serve you with a description of how to do it.