# How do I run individual testcases in a cppunit runner?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, visual-c++, boost, cppunit

The following piece of code gets all my tests and their testcases and runs them. I am trying to get a few individual testcases and get them alone to run. How do I achieve that?

```
CPPUNIT_NS::TestFactoryRegistry &reg = CPPUNIT_NS::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry("");
CPPUNIT_NS::TextUi::TestRunner runner;   //the runner
runner.addTest(reg.makeTest());
bool wasSucessful = runner.run();
```

I read that you can iterater through the testcases by getting the list using getTests(), but I was not sure how to do that.

Can someone please help me?

EDIT1:
I would like to run individual testcases from a test(which has multiple testcases). I would like to run run just one testcase.

For example,
We could have a Test, named "Mathematical Operations" and that has multiple test cases like, "Mathematical Operations.TestAdd" and "Mathematical Operations.TestSubtract". I want to be able to run just "TestAdd" and not run the whole Test  of "Mathematical Operations".

Thanks!

Comment: This is a possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783690/how-to-run-subset-of-unit-tests-in-cppunit-by-selecting-them-at-run-time

Comment: I already looked at that. It looks like it talks about how to get a specific test and run it. I am interested in running a specific testcase inside a test.

Answer (score 0):

The ask mentioned in this question is a duplicate of [How to run subset of unit tests in CPPUnit by selecting them at run-time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783690/how-to-run-subset-of-unit-tests-in-cppunit-by-selecting-them-at-run-time)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2786251/2130670) answer on the question does provide a solution.